# HTML Table column and ruby array create additional columns

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am creating an html table for exam results which should look like this. the overall and finall grade is a rowspan(count of array of tests)

Test1, 2 and 3 all belongs to an array, ie tests and are displayed by using ruby array.each syntax. the problem is that the overall and final grade columns are repeated for each test so the table displays like this

how do i limit the table from creating additional columns for each array element?

Comment: Look like what? copy and paste fail?

Answer (score 0):

The table key and value points can be easily seperated by the usage of both

```
<tr>(table row)</tr>
```

and

`<td>(table data)</td>`

I would suggest reading: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Have fun